# Conditionally check checkboxes

Tags: visualforce-component

Requirement:-

Apex compoenet with a checkbox field. This component is used in page1. A command button on page1 when clicked the checkbox in component must be checked.

Please check what i have tried so far

```
<apex:component controller="Test">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputcheckbox disabled="true" selected="{!checked}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Page1:-

```
<apex:page controller="Test">
  <apex:commandButton value="Checking the checkbox in component" action="{!test}" />
</table>
</apex:page>

Controller code

public with sharing class Test 
{
    public Boolean checked { get; set; }

    public Test() 
    {
         checked = false;
    }

    public pageReference test()
    {
        checked = true;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you gotten stuck? Unless you show what you've done, tried and failed with you're unlikely to get a good answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your page, component, and controller are slightly off in subtle ways, but you're closer than you realize. Here's a set of code that should work:

### Controller

```
public with sharing class myController {
    public Boolean myCheckbox { get { return myCheckbox != null && myCheckbox; } set; }
    public void toggleMyCheckBox() { myCheckbox = !myCheckbox; }
}
```

### Component

```
<apex:component selfClosing="true" controller="myController">
    <apex:attribute assignTo="{!myCheckBox}" name="checked"
        type="Boolean" required="true" description="A box (obviously)" />
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myCheckbox}"/>
</apex:component>
```

### Page

```
<apex:page controller="myController">
    <apex:form>
        <c:myCheckbox checked="{!myCheckbox}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!toggleMyCheckbox}" value="Click Me!"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It isn't necessary that the page and component use the same controller (but it makes programming it easier). What is important is that you need a value that appears in common in both the page controller and component controller (because we need two-way communication between the page and component).

The form has to contain all action elements, so we shouldn't use a form inside the component since there are action items outside the component. Therefore, the form was moved to the page in my example. Usually, components will not have their own form tag, although there are rare exceptions when this is acceptable.

I set the default value "false" differently, but a normal constructor would work, too.